# How to compare two String in Objective -C Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, asp.net-web-api

I am  checking user credential from WebAPI `userId` and `userPWD` and checking them. If User is valid then he access the app. If not then I am showing `AlertView` Controller to user that he is not valid user. How to do that?

My code is here:

```
if ([jstr isEqualToString:@"Invalide Login Credential."])
{
    UIAlertController *alert =
          [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter valid Details." message:@"invalid" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    
    UIAlertAction* ok = 
          [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
    {                                                                         
       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];                                                                         
    }];
    [alert addAction:ok];
    
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    
    NSLog(@"Invalide Login Credential.");
    
    //Invalide Login Credential.
}
```

Response for it is here:

```
Jstr = Invalide Login Credential.
```

Comment: can you show your json parsing, else  add some additional code

Comment: I think this one is wrong jstr

Comment: The code is right, use isEqualToString to compare two strings. 
If it doesn't work, insert a breakpoint (or a NSLog) on the first line of your code and check the jstr value.

Answer (score 1):

```c
if([jstr isEqualToString:@"Invalide Login Credential."])
{
    //Invalide Login Credential. with UIAlertController
}
else
{
    //valid user, do whatever you want the conditions here
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 if ([jstr rangeOfString:@"Invalide Login Credential." options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound) {
      // show error alertViewControler
 }
 else {
    NSLog(@"matched");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

== compares the address of the objects, not their content. Two different objects will obviously never have the same address.
To compare strings use NSString's isEqualToString: method:

```
if ([string1 isEqualToString:string2]) {
NSLog(@"it is equal");
```

}

Note the square brackets [ ]. This is the proper Objective-C syntax for sending messages (i.e. calling functions).